# Whats the difference between Acer Aspire AS7740-5691 and Acer Aspire AS7740-5142?

Tags: laptop, comparison, acer-aspire

- [Acer Aspire AS7740-5142](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834115739)
- [Acer Aspire AS7740-5691](http://www.staples.com/Acer-Aspire-AS7740-5691-Laptop/product_851638?cm_mmc=GoogleBase-_-Shopping-_-Technology%3ELaptops_%26_Accessories-_-851638-LX.SA70X.066#ReviewHeader)

I'm scratching my head over the large ($150+) price difference that I'm finding between these two problems.  The only thing I can see is that one comes with 500gb and another with 320gb hard-disk.

Can anyone tell me why I could possibly want the more expensive version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the larger hard drive, the more expensive laptop has a bluray player.  Those two things alone could easily account for 150 bucks difference

Comment: Ah ok, thanks.  I missed that.  Don't care about blue-ray so I get to save money weee!